# Neighbor’s gutters empty into my sump pump discharge

Tags: sump-pump, gutters

I’m in CT in the US.

My sump pump discharges into my front lawn near the sidewalk. My gutters also feed into this, and I found out recently that my neighbor’s gutters do as well. My neighbor told me that when the previous homeowner hooked his gutters up to the discharge pipe he asked the neighbor if he wanted him to hook his gutters up to it too and he said sure. Now, I like this neighbor, he’s a nice old man and I currently have no desire to make any changes here. But I’m curious, if something were to change in the future and I felt that having his gutters empty on the edge of my lawn was just too much, what would my options be here? (We’ve already done a bunch of landscaping to try to soak up extra water around the discharge pipe — I’m mostly concerned that in the future we might feel that there’s just too much water flowing into our yard, especially in the winter when it’ll go onto the sidewalk and freeze.)

Comment: As usual, photos would help a lot here, as well as an idea of what sort of weather you encounter (rain intensity and frequency).

Comment: I’ll try to get some photos next time I’m home but most of it is underground so I’m not sure how useful they’d be. We get a good amount of rain in spring but I’m more concerned about stuff freezing up in the winter — less rain then, so at least there’s that.

Comment: When you say "into my front lawn" what do you mean?  You have a drain pipe buried under your lawn that runs from your house to the street?

Comment: It’s buried under my lawn and it pops up and discharges about two feet away from the front edge of the lawn. Since the lawn grades down away from the house it ends up flowing onto the sidewalk.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds more like a legal issue, probably (check their rules) better suited for [law.se] than here. Especially based on the two answers that have been provided so far.

Answer (score 3):

In most places, town ordinances forbid you from dumping your water into the neighbor's property at the property line. So let's say the old man dies or sells the house, you'd be within your rights to request the new owners that they fix this. If they refuse, you go to the town building department and file a complaint.

Answer (score 1):

If there were no provisions written that attach to the deed, (Highly doubtful) you can do as you wish. No agreement between the previous owner and the new owner, (you) transfers.

You have the right to take care of your property. However you wish to be a good neighbor.  The best course will probably be a conversation with your neighbor about the conditions that are being experienced and a "suggestion" as to how to correct it.  Should the neighbor not be agreeable, do what is needed for your property and leave him to care for his.